# Null pointer exception when testing in Java

Tags: java, string, netbeans, nullpointerexception

```
public boolean isItMyName(String name)
    {    
       name = fullname.substring(0,fullname.indexOf(' '));
       ...
    }
```

Then my code goes on and on. When I run this, I get a null pointer exception and the error is pointing to this line.

I also created a JUnit tester, where it tests whether the input is true or false.

```
Name myName = new Name();
assertEquals(false, myName.isItMyName("Troll");
```

It also gives me a null pointer exception at `assertEquals(false, myName.isItMyName("Troll"));`

I'm at my wit's end. How do I fix this?

@ Greg Hewgill:

In my Name class, I do this:

```
public class Name(String n)
{
  name = n;
}
```

But in my main method, I pass in the string: Name myName = new Name("Johnathy");

So string isn't null.

FULLNAME:

```
public class EmailAddress {
private String address;



public EmailAddress(String a)
{
  address = a;

}

public String toString()
{
    return address;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of variable/field "fullname"? Might it be null?

Comment: Well, looks like the `fullname` variable you are using on this line is null. So the question is: where are you initializing this variable to something other than it's default value of null?

Comment: Are you sure that `fullname` is not `null`?

Comment: @MacosxIam: You do realise that the object you create in a `main` method *isn't the same object as you're creating in your unit test*?

Comment: Now you've significantly changed your question, calling two different `Name` constructors in different situations, and introduced code for `EmailAddress` which appears unrelated. I'm afraid I'm lost now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you're ignoring your parameter... you're assigning a new value to `name` in the first line. That means your method is almost certainly broken to start with.

Then consider where `fullname` (which I assume is an instance variable) is going to come from. Unless you're setting it to a value within your parameterless constructor, it's going to be `null` by default. Is that really what you want?

I suggest you change your `Name` class to *only* have constructors taking name parameters, and that you validate that they're not null. That way you can never have an invalid `Name` object, where the full name is `null`.

EDIT: Now you've posted more code, look at your parameterless constructor and the `setName` method:

```
public Name()
{
   setName(fullname);     
}

public void setName(String n)
{
    fullname = n;
}
```

That means your parameterless constructor is equivalent to:

```
public Name()
{
   fullname = fullname;
}
```

... i.e. a no-op. `fullname` will be null, hence the exception.

My advice is to get rid of the parameterless constructor entirely, and make the other one validate the parameter.

Comment: But aren't I just defining what name is? That's what I want to do.

Comment: @MacosxIam: No, you've *already* declared `name` as the parameter for the method. So before executing the first line of the method, the value of `name` would be the reference to "Troll". Then you're trying to set the value to a *different* value (the substring of `fullName`). It may be worth going over parameters in whatever book/tutorial you're learning from, even before you tackle the null reference problem.

Comment: I deleted the parameter and created a String with those instructions (substring). Still a null pointer exception. It means that the parameters had NOTHING to do with the error.

Comment: @MacosxIam: No, they don't have to do with the error - that's due to `fullname`, which the rest of my answer is about. But it's *vital* that you understand the parameter problem too.

Comment: @MacosxIam: Edited with more details about what's happening in your current code.

Comment: @MacosxIam: If you've removed the parameterless constructor then presumably you've changed the test code (as that was *calling* the parameterless constructor). Please update your post with the new test code.

Answer (score 3):

```
   name = fullname.substring(0,fullname.indexOf(' '));
```

If you get a null pointer exception on that line, then `fullname` is `null`. It's really the only possibility.

Comment: @MacosxIam: Yes, but a string can be `null`, especially if you haven't assigned anything else to it. From the code you posted, it looks like you've still got some practice to do. Good luck, use the debugger, and keep asking questions!

Comment: Nit: A *String* can't be null... the evaluation of a String-typed expression may result in null, but a +1 still. Gravity exists. ;-)

Comment: @MacosxIam: That's not what you showed in your original question, where your JUnit tester does `Name myName = new Name();` (using the no-parameter constructor). The no-parameter constructor takes the value of `fullname` (which is `null`, because that's what it starts as), calls `setName(null)`, which assigns `fullname = null`. In that case, it's a roundabout way of doing nothing. Perhaps you could do `fullname = ""` in your no-parameter constructor, so `fullname` starts off as an empty string and not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Without more code I can't say for sure, but I bet you `fullname` is null and never set to anything.

Answer (score 0):

if no ' ' index is found in the full name wouldnt it return -1 thus causing substring to grab 0,-1 which is null... perhaps toss it in an if and skip that step if the index is < 0... and shouldnt your parameter that is incomming be fullname

Comment: Actually, substring() would throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in this case. You wouldn't see a NPE.